# How to custom Sort an json array in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is My array.

```
Data = [
    0: { label: "Adults - 35 to 64", value: 38.2 },
    1: { label: "Young Adult- 16 to 34", value: 20.76 },
    2: { label: "Senior - 65+", value: 41.04 }
];
```

what I'm expecting is:

```
Data = [
    0: { label: "Young Adult- 16 to 34", value: 20.76 },
    1: { label: "Adults - 35 to 64", value: 38.2 },
    2: { label: "Senior - 65+", value: 41.04 }
];
```

I want to change the index using label.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
let x = Data.sort((a, b) => (a.label > b.label ? 1 : -1));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).